# Behaviour of diamagnetic substance in a magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, material-science

We know that in a diamagnetic substance, all electrons are paired up, hence there is no reason for a diamagnetic substance to interact with a magnetic field. But we know that diamagnetic substances weakly repel magnetic field i.e. for diamagnetic substance $\chi<0$. I would like to know what causes this interaction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is diamagnetism a static or dynamic effect?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256590/is-diamagnetism-a-static-or-dynamic-effect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a result of Lenz law. Diamagnetic properties arise from the realignment of the electron paths under the influence of an external magnetic field.  They realign in a manner so as to oppose the external magnetic field in accordance with Lenz' law.

Also, Diamagnetism is shown by all substances. It's just that those substances we call paramagnetic, ferromagnetic etc. have other properties of attraction to external magnetic field in front of which effect of diamagnetism is negligible.